# I Can't break out of ...> in SQLite shell

Tags: sqlite

I'm learning **`SQLite`** and I guess I entered something wrong, but now I'm stuck where anything I enter it just keeps showing "...>"

```
SQLite create kitchen_table(food_name TEXT UNIQUE,food_type TEXT,quantity INT)";
...>;
...>:
...>
...>.quit
...>^D
...>^D
```

As you can see, I've tried both semi-colon and ctrl-D, which are the two answers I found online.

Answer (score 1):

Near the very end of the first line is an open quote: `"`.

Close that, followed by a semicolon, and you'll escape with a nice syntax error.

```
sqlite> create kitchen_table(food_name TEXT UNIQUE,food_type TEXT,quantity INT)";
   ...> "
   ...> ;
Error: near "kitchen_table": syntax error
```

You're also likely looking for `CREATE TABLE`, not just `CREATE`. See the [language documentation](http://sqlite.org/lang.html).

Answer (score -1):

Oka's right. The double-quote at the end of the query string might be your issue. Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE kitchen_table ( 
food_name text UNIQUE,
food_type text,
quantity integer);
```

Note the data types and syntax for SQLite